# Ways to determine the version of Firebird SQL?

Tags: c++, delphi, firebird

Is there any way to determine which version of Firebird SQL is running?  Using SQL or code (Delphi, C++).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to find it via SQL you can use [get_context](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-get-context.html) to find the engine version it with the following:

```
SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') 
             as version from rdb$database;
```

you can read more about it here [firebird faq](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq223/), but it requires Firebird 2.1 I believe.

Comment: Why did you use 2 single quotes in 'system' and 'engine_version' query fails that way, but with single quotes returns proper result

Comment: @Re0sless: Given that this will bomb for all versions before FB 2.1, isn't that cheating? Would you call a Vista-only API function and catch the possible crashes only to find out what Windows version the program runs on? The question was awfully vague, but this feels just wrong.

Comment: I have installed Firebird 2.5. I get following error after issuing above command:
***
Starting transaction...
Preparing query: SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION')
from rdb$database
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION')
from rdb$database )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -804
An error was found in the application program input parameters for the SQL statement.

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
Function unknown
RDB$GET_CONTEXT

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can do:

- Use the Services API to query the server version, the call is [`isc_service_query()`](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&s=1247418314:3809&page=ibp_60_api_iscsq_fs) with the `isc_info_svc_server_version` parameter. Your preferred Delphi component set should surface a method to wrap this API.
  For C++ there is for example [IBPP](http://www.ibpp.org) which has `IBPP::Service::GetVersion()` to return the version string.
  What you get back with these is the same string that is shown in the control panel applet.
- If you need to check whether certain features are available it may be enough (or even better) to execute statements against the system tables to check whether a given system relation or some field in that relation is available. If the ODS of the database is from an older version some features may not be supported, even though the server version is recent enough.
  The ODS version can also be queried via the API, use the `isc_database_info()` call.

Comment: You can also query the server version and the server version string using a regular connection instead of the Services API, using the isc_database_info function with the isc_info_version parameter (you can also query the ODS version with isc_database_info). Another way of getting version information could be the isc_version function.

Answer (score -1):

May be you have FIBPlus ( http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/ ) ... it has all the tools and sources necessary to install, uninstall, start, stop Firebird/Interbase and also to get the version of the server and more. In any case, you can get the version from the client driver (fbclient.dll for Firebird). DelphiDabbler ( http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/verinfo/download ) has free sources that get file version of any DLL. You can easily use that.

Comment: The version of the client library has nothing to do with the version of the server, different versions can be mixed and matched easily. Even with a local server the client library may well have a different version.

Comment: OK - That i did not know. Looking at my actual GDS32.DLL i get: Translation = Anglais (États-Unis) - Windows 3.1 US (ANSI) / Multilingual CompanyName = Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
FileDescription = InterBase Server FileVersion = WI-V9.0.2.420
InternalName = InterBase  LegalCopyright = Copyright (c) 1986 - 2008 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. ProductName = InterBase Server ProductVersion = 9.0.2.420

Comment: For Firebird FBCLIENT.DLL: FileDescription = Firebird SQL Server  FileVersion = WI-V2.1.2.18118 InternalName = Firebird  LegalCopyright = All Copyright (c) retained by individual contributors - original code Copyright (c) 2000 Inprise Corporation
ProductName = Firebird SQL Server ProductVersion = 2.1.2.18118
SpecialBuild = Firebird 2.1

Comment: And this client library version makes only sense when the database is on localhost, otherwise the Firebird server could be for example 1.5.5 on Linux or some other *nix. Asking the server is the only way to be sure.