# Cannot run multiple insert record query in firebird via C#

Tags: c#, database, firebird

I am generating a multiple insert records query in C# and trying to execute in FireBird.

When I am running it on FlameRobin it works so well. But When I am running it via C# it throws exception.

```
SET TERM ^ ; INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE; ^ SET TERM ; ^
```

Exception in C# code is

> {"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -104\r\nToken unknown - line 1, char 5\r\nTERM"}

C# Code is

```
string sQuery = "SET TERM ^ ; INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE; ^ SET TERM ; ^ ";
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SQLHelp.Connectionstring, CommandType.Text, sQuery);
```

Any idea whats wrong I am doing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`set term`](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq78/) statements you're including are not part of Firebird SQL language, but is a kind of *interpreter configuration instruction* firstly introduced in **isql**, which is the command line client for Firebird.

Look at your script this way:

```
SET TERM ^ ; 

INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 
  SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE 
  UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE 
  UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE; ^ 

SET TERM ; ^
```

The engine doesn't know and can't process the `set term` statements.

FlameRobin and other clients add support for the `set term` statement for compatibility: to allow running SQL scripts written for isql, or because they lacks a fully SQL parser and still needs to properly recognize where a statement ends when a script includes semi-colons. But all this clients, once a statement is delimited inside a script, doesn't send the `set term` to the engine, just ignores it.

You have to do the same: remove the `set term` statements and send the unique other statement you have, like this:

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 
  SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE 
  UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE 
  UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Be aware you must also remove the `;`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used ur query now getting exception "{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -104\r\nToken unknown - line 1, char 62\r\nUNION"}"

Comment: @DJ Well, it is your query, not mine ;). Try sending three separate inserts. Remember the database engine accepts only one SQL command per request, but you can wrap the three in a Execute Block, if you want to avoid three database round-trips.

Comment: actually I need to insert 1000 records at once. thats why i need somthing same

Comment: Don't forget in a program, you can just write a loop that repeats 1000 times to insert 1000 records one by one ;)

Comment: which firebird version are you using?

Comment: @jachgute - Actually I tried that but its takes 3 secs to insert 1000 records in db.In future i might need to insert 1 million records also. About firebird version I don't know how to find it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248079/ways-to-determine-the-version-of-firebird-sql

Comment: BTW, there's no server I know which supports sending such a large SQL statement you have in mind to insert a million rows on a single call!

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not conform to the Firebird syntax. Drivers can only execute a single statement at a time (be aware that an `EXECUTE BLOCK` is considered to be a single statement).
You should not use `SET TERM`, that is an artifact of the ISQL tool (and some other query tools like FlameRobin) and is not actually part of the Firebird SQL language.

Nor should you include `;` in a query. Those are only valid in 1) PSQL (stored procedures, triggers and inside `EXECUTE BLOCK`) and 2) once again in tools like ISQL to separate (end) statements.

So using the following query on its own should be sufficient:

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

**EDIT**

As I commented, maybe the parser doesn't understand `UNION` when combined with an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Using a sub-select will probably work:

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 
  SELECT column1, column2 FROM (
     SELECT '2' AS column1, 'two ' AS column2 FROM RDB$DATABASE 
     UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE 
     UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE
  )
```

**EDIT 2**

I just tested it with the the code below and it works: the expected rows are inserted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var constrBuilder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
    constrBuilder.DataSource = "localhost";
    constrBuilder.Database = @"D:\data\db\testdatabase.fdb";
    constrBuilder.UserID = "sysdba";
    constrBuilder.Password = "masterkey";

    string constr = constrBuilder.ToString();

    using (var con = new FbConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var trans = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var cmd = new FbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'five' FROM RDB$DATABASE";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried but still getting exception "{"Dynamic SQL Error\r\nSQL error code = -104\r\nToken unknown - line 1, char 59\r\nUNION"}".

Comment: Possibly the parser doesn't like `UNION` with an `INSERT` you may need to wrap the query in another one (eg `SELECT column1, column2 FROM (<your current select>)`

Comment: sorry I did nt get this `<your current select>`. Can you give me an example.

Comment: I am really thankful for your responses. But actually your all options are working correctly if I execute it in FlameRobin but when I am executing the statements in C#. Its throwing the error again. Looks like the problem is not with the query.

Comment: statement `INSERT INTO COUNTRY1 
  SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM 
RDB$DATABASE ` also works fine but the moment I try multiple inserts it starts throwing exception.

Comment: @DJ I don't have Firebird available here, I will see if I can check this in more detail tonight.

Comment: @DJ I just tested the query with Firebird 2.5.2 and the Firebird .NET provider 3.0.2 (as on NuGet) and the query simply works

Comment: I am getting the exception "unable to complete the request to host localhost". Just fyi, I dont have fdb server. I am working on a file.